# Razor ForEach, Get value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using razor syntax to generate a list of labels.

```
@foreach(var label in Model.Labels)
{
   @Html.Label(label, new  { id = "??" }) <br /> <br />
}
```

It renders like this:

item1

item2

What must I do in Jquery to be able to alert the name of the label that was clicked?

If I give it a static Id, the click event only fires on the first element which is because  there is multiple labels with the same ID.

Comment: Have you tried using a `class` or a `data-` attribute instead of `id`? Then you listen for that class getting clicked and use `$(this)` to see which element.

Comment: uptown, how can I implement that?

Comment: `class = "myLabelClass"` then `$(document).on('click', '.myLabelClass', function() { alert($(this).html()); })` You might need to tweak that alert a little I didn't test it with `.html()` but you get the idea.

Comment: Worked perfectly, if you want to make it answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1, use `data-*` 
Razor:

```
@foreach(var label in Model.Labels)
{
   @Html.Label(label, new  { data_type = "myLableType" }) <br /> <br />
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-type="myLabelType"]', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
}
```

Option 2, use `class` - class is intended to be used for CSS styling not JS but it will work:

Razor:

```
@foreach(var label in Model.Labels)
{
   @Html.Label(label, new  { class= "myLableType" }) <br /> <br />
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myLabelType', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to concern yourself with an ID - unless you really want / need to.

You can do this in In your view:

```
    @foreach(var label in Model.Labels)
    {
       @Html.LabelFor(x => label, new  { @Class = "clickableLabel" }) <br /> <br />
    }
```

In jquery:

```
    $(".clickableLabel").click(function ()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    })
```

By using a class, you would be able to click on multiple labels whilst using the same event.

Comment: Just had to substitute `alert($(this).html()));` and it worked

Comment: Great! Like @SparoHawk also mentioned, depending on what you need you can also take advantage of the `data-` attributes of HTML5 that MVC utilizes and access it with jquery e.g.: `$(this).data("name");`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an ID for each label. It all depends on your HTML structure. If your labels are nested inside another element, you can have that parent element with an ID and then use jQuery to handle the children label: `$('#divWithId').children('label').click(function(){})`.

Otherwise, as pointed out, you could use a class or `data-` property to access the labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a div wrapping all your labels, then you can use jquery to do something like the below.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGaUb/). Hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#labelContainer').children().on("click", function(){
                        alert($(this).text());                    
                        }); 
});


<div id="labelContainer">
    <label>test1</label>
    <label>test2</label>
    <label>test3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the labels themselves as IDs.

```
@foreach(var label in Model.Labels)
{
   @Html.Label(label, new  { id = label }) <br /> <br />
}
```

If that doesn't guarantee uniqueness, add some string to the beginning or end of the id.

Comment: I knew some Unique Id would have to be given, and yes this would work. But how you would select them in JQuery and be able to determine which was clicked?